# How to check if checkbox is checked in asp.net view using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to find out whenever a checkbox on my page is checked and unchecked.  I console log to find out the status, but I am always getting an "unchecked" result. What am I doing wrong?

```
...
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_addAuthor" name="checkbox_addAuthor" />

</div>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkbox = $('#checkbox_addAuthor');
    var authorList = $('#AuthorList');

    checkbox.on('click',function(){

        if(checkbox.Checked == true)
        {
           console.log("I am checked")
        }
        else {
            console.log("I am not checked");
        }

    })

</script>
}
```

When I run this, the console always prints out "I am not checked". Cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `prop`

```
if($('#checkbox_addAuthor').prop('checked'))
 {
    // something when checked
 }
else {
   // something else when not
 }
```

Comment: This works properly, thank you. But do you know/could you explain why my way of doing it does not work properly.

Comment: @Mike i guess you mistake was here on  ` if(checkbox.Checked == true)` line. .Check is a .net property to check a checkbox control is checked but in javascript(also jquery) the `Check` property doesnt really exist?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkbox_addAuthor :checkbox:checked').length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#checkbox_addAuthor').val() == "on"` to check the state of the checkbox